# Cannot create contract from another contract - truffle and ganache

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-test, ganache-cli

I'm trying to write a test with ganache and truffle to create a contract instance from another contract.

Everything works in Remix but it doesn't in ganache. This is the code

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledFactory = require('../build/contracts/EntityFactory.json');
const compiledEntity = require('../build/contracts/Entity.json');

let accounts;
let factory;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledFactory.abi)
    .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '6721975' });

  // create rootEntity
  console.log('create root entity from account: ' + accounts[1]);
  try {
    await factory.methods.createEntity().send({
      from: accounts[1],
      gas: '1000000'
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  console.log('created root entity');
});

describe('Entities', () => {
  it('deploys a factory and an entity', () => {
    console.log(factory.options.address);
  });
});
```

The console output I receive after runnung "truffle test" is:

```
create root entity from account: 0x5DE926288f995e7F916f2348894C200545804714
c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Function.c.fromResults (/Users/....../ethereum/transparency/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:157333)
    at A.processBlock (/Users/....../ethereum/transparency/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:17:121734)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5) {
  name: 'c',
  results: {
    '0xeed3e78f724bd4c079efda4192df9b95684a45f3789e9c93594dce663a42ccff': {
      error: 'revert',
      program_counter: 2198,
      return: '0x',
      reason: undefined
    }
  },
  hashes: [
    '0xeed3e78f724bd4c079efda4192df9b95684a45f3789e9c93594dce663a42ccff'
  ],
  message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: revert'
}
created root entity
assign address root
assigned address root
create child entity
    1) "before each" hook for "deploys a factory and an entity"


  0 passing (533ms)
  1 failing

  1) "before each" hook for "deploys a factory and an entity":
     c: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Function.c.fromResults (node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:2:157333)
      at A.processBlock (node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:17:121734)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Here's the EntityFactory code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract EntityFactory {
    Entity[] public deployedEntities;
    mapping(address => bool) public deployedEntitiesMap;

    function createEntity() public {
        Entity newEntity = new Entity(msg.sender);
        deployedEntitiesMap[newEntity] = true;
        deployedEntities.push(newEntity);
    }

    function getDeployedEntities() public view returns(Entity[]) {
        return deployedEntities;
    }
}
```

The Entity's constructor:

```
function Entity(address creatorAcc) public {
    creator = creatorAcc;
    manager = creatorAcc;
    isManaged = false;
}
```

I'm completely new with ethereum, just learning!
Thanks

Comment: the createEntity is relevant , please post its code

Comment: I've added it at the end @MajdTL

Comment: The `Entity` constructor is also relevant, please post its code.

Comment: @goodvibration here it is
as I said, with remix no issue at all

Comment: if i try to use truffle console to create the factory i get this after creating it and calling it {
  address: [Getter/Setter],
  jsonInterface: [Getter/Setter],
  data: undefined,
  from: undefined,
  gasPrice: undefined,
  gas: undefined
}

Comment: Maybe nothing to do with the error but why is your beforeeach outside the describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code looks as if it was not written for Truffle:**

1. The following is not needed, since it is already provided by the framework:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

2. You can and should use the source contract instead of the compiled contract:

```
const compiledFactory = require('../build/contracts/EntityFactory.json');
const compiledEntity = require('../build/contracts/Entity.json');
```

---

**For example, try this:**

```
const EntityFactory = artifacts.require('EntityFactory');
const Entity = artifacts.require('Entity');

let factory;

contract('Test', (accounts) => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        factory = await EntityFactory.new({from: accounts[0]});
        await factory.createEntity({from: accounts[1]});
    });

    it('test 1', async () => {
        ...
        assert(...);
    });

    it('test 2', async () => {
        ...
        assert(...);
    });

    it('test 3', async () => {
        ...
        assert(...);
    });
});
```

---

Finally, before you run `truffle test`, start `ganache-cli`, for example:

```
ganache-cli --port=8545 --gasPrice=20000000000 --gasLimit=6721975
```

This will provide you with a Ganache node with 10 unlocked accounts.

Comment: Great! I was following an outdated tutorial while I was trying to use truffle. I removed the lines you said and adapted the tests and now everything works! thanks a lot